Blazor 8 Server - @Onclick not triggering the function in code even with rendermode = InteractiveServer
I have this component :
@using Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<AccountUser> SignInManager
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@rendermode InteractiveServer


<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 bg-light " style="width: 260px;overflow: auto;">
    <a href="/" class="text-decoration-none">
        <div><img src="images/logo.png" style="width:200px;" /></div>
    </a>
    <hr />

    <button class="btn btn-link align-items-center link-dark text-decoration-none" @onclick="LogoutUser" style="padding: 0; border: none; background: none;">
        <i class="bi bi-door-closed"></i> &nbsp;Logout
    </button>
</div>

@code {
    private async Task LogoutUser()
    {
        await SignInManager.SignOutAsync();
        Navigation.NavigateTo("/login", true);
    }
}

When I'm clicking on the "Logout" button, nothing happens, the private async Task LogoutUser() is not called.
I tried to add @rendermode InteractiveServer, but the issue remains the same.
When I'm using <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" /> in App.razor, I got this error message :

InvalidOperationException: There is already a subscriber to the content with the given section ID 'System.Object'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Sections.SectionRegistry.Subscribe(object identifier, SectionOutlet subscriber)

I tried many solutions related to this kind of issue that I found in Stackoverflow, but nothing works for me.

So is it that you cannot unsubscribe, or that you subscribe twice?

I tested your code and found no errors with the @onclick, so could you please share a demo project that can reproduce this issue? Alternatively, you can create a new project to test your code and verify if the issue persists.
